# Should websites provide high contrast or alternate schemes?

Tags: website-design, accessibility, color

With regards to Accessibility, many sites focus on font-size adjustments either the browser's / OS's native controls or via a control on the page (usually denoted by 3 capital A's of varying size).

However, there are some instances where a contrast adjustment may be needed. Webpages can be affected by the OS's high contrast mode ([mentioned here with screen shot](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/27992/is-high-contrast-mode-really-useful)); however, depending on the stylesheet, this may end up being a mess.

Because of this, should websites that have higher accessibility requirements provide options for the visitor to select a style / color scheme that provides a higher contrast than the default? If so, should there be varying degrees or just normal and the extreme high contrast mode that's look like the OS's version?

Comment: The OS theming should only affect the border and menu of the browser, the page will still be the same (unless you change the defaults of the browser).

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/ mobile website has a light / dark theme on the bottom - I personally love using the different themes in different viewing situations (outdoors with sunlight vs insides). All in all, marginal on publisher level, though, it seems to me.

Answer (score 4):

From what I found here: [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT/#themes)
my answer to

> Because of this, should websites that have higher accessibility requirements provide options for the visitor to select a style / color scheme that provides a higher contrast than the default?

would be 'Yes'.

And the following resources imply:

- [5 Ways to Ensure Your Site Is Accessible to the Visually Impaired](http://mashable.com/2011/04/20/design-for-visually-impaired/)
- [The Visually Impaired Web User's Technology](https://www.afb.org/about-afb/what-we-do/afb-consulting/afb-accessibility-resources/users-technology)
- [Web Accessibility Resources](http://www.afb.org/Section.aspx?SectionID=57&TopicID=167&DocumentID=2177)

Many people would like it if you provide:

> varying degrees of contrast modes

Answer (score 0):

Note that many browsers provide built in support to override a page's CSS with custom CSS.  For example, Opera has a special "accessibility mode" setting.  I think providing accessibility schemes is of value (and if you already support theming, it's a no-brainer).  However, having your page designed to work properly when the user is making use of an accessibility-oriented browsing tool will resolve this problem more effectively.  For example, alternate themes aren't inherently helpful to blind users.

Providing alternate themes is a nice feature to offer, and will likely make many users happier, even if those users don't "need" such features.  Further, in a well-designed site, providing custom themes is often pretty cheap.