# Examples needed: a toggle that shows a higher-contrast version of a site

Tags: website-design, accessibility, web

Can someone give me examples of a feature that toggles to a high-contrast version of the website?

I am only able to find 2 live website examples:

> https://www.smashingmagazine.com/?source=post_page---------------------------
>
> https://turbotax.intuit.com/

I am doing a toggle switch to increase the contrast on my e-commerce website but was not able to find many other e-commerce website doing so.

Can someone give me a reference to this color-contrast toggle which other websites are using?

I want a reference for those sites which actually uses this feature

Comment: I've never noticed this feature before. It makes me wonder why the site isn't just designed to meet WCAG contrast recommendations in the first place.

Comment: It's not hard to meet the WCAG AA Contrast criterion, but the AAA can be rather difficult if you do not want to sacrifice the aesthetics, in my opinion. But adding a toggle like this is an oft recommended way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Website References:

- https://www.choicehotels.com/
- https://www.dunkindonuts.com
- https://www.saudia.com/

I think this is part of WCAG 2.0 requirement to provide [minimum contrast ratio](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html) guidelines. Success criterion 1.4.3 and 1.4.6 mentions providing a style switcher to high contrast for the users with visual impairments.

More info can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G174

Also this answer might help as well: [Should websites provide high contrast or alternate schemes?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42053/should-websites-provide-high-contrast-or-alternate-schemes)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an example, but some thoughts about such a toggle:

- If you use a WCAG 2.0 conform contrast in the first place the toggle wouldn't be necessary. And there are more benefits in that: the readability of your site will be enhanced for all users.
- Having a toggle might make some user feel handicapped because they need to change the settings of the site to better access it. It is a better experience for does users just to be able to access the site anyway without having to manipulate it first.

So, my recommendation is, make your site accessible right away and not only on demand...

Comment: Some websites & products have brand colors that doesn't comply with WCAG 2.0 minimum contrast requirements, So as a quick fix they provide a high contrast version for the users who prefer it. Changing brand colors and guidelines is a more time consuming thing than providing an alternate version for the user for time being. Also many websites have color blind version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this the other day that is super helpful. It has really nice combinations of colours with strong accessibility grades. http://clrs.cc/a11y/

I also use this tool: https://color.review/