# Correct way to present an option for visual deficiency (ie. colorblindness)

Tags: accessibility, color, color-blindness

I would like to present an option for users who have a visual deficiency (specifically, colorblindness) to choose so that the UI can adjust its colors accordingly to best suit them. What should I name this option?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [High Contrast Mode](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/highcont.htm)? There is a [Stack Overflow Question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/27992/is-high-contrast-mode-really-useful) about how useful that is too.

Comment: Is this option a switch between color schemes or does it open a menu with more accessibility options?

Comment: If your site needs to be 508 compliant, you'll need all of your text and background to meet the AA standard: http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/. The 508 rules are getting updated this year and will include AA contrast as a minimum standard. http://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-ict-refresh

Comment: High contrast seems to be the way to go. Is there a case where a person with a type of color blindness would not want to use a high contrast setting, but still would like to adjust the colors to better suit their type of colorblindness (protanopia, deuteranopia etc.)?

Comment: @PixelGraph those links will be helpful for when I choose colors with sufficient contrast. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Accessibility" is a really large topic, including color choices, but also extending to screen reader support, or timing requirements. If all you do is switch the colors (as I assume from your question), for your safety you should choose a more focussed term.

"High Contrast Theme" would be one possibility.

Comment: Okay. I was planning to have an option for High Contrast mode and a "Colorblindness" mode. Would you say that is redundant?

Comment: From my experience, high contrast is usually a means to support colorblind users. Therefore, I'd say these two are redundant.